# supersimple jQuery load

Tags: jquery, load

This simple code just do not load anything, where's the problem?

```
<head>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/load.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid bgres">
            <div class="container main" id="gora">

        </div>
</div>

</body>
```

load.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#gora").load("gora.txt");
});
```

gora.txt is just html cut out from the same place

i'm trying to pretend php include function

Comment: What does the NET tab of your browser dev tool show?

Comment: Did you load your js correctly, should it be `<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/js/load.js"></script>`, because relative path sometimes will be wrong on different urls

Comment: jQuery is working, so i assume path is correct
both js files are in the same folder

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? Does your server serve `.txt` files via HTTP?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/ikad/Desktop/Jettro2/gora.txt. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     $.ajax( "sample.txt" )
       .done(function(data) {
         $("#gora").html(data);
     });
```

- Run the html file in HTTP (i.e) localhost protocol don't run in FTP
  [image]

Comment: Download Webserver for chrome
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en

Comment: Thank You very much